# Upgrading from TFS 2015 to DevOps 2022

Tags: tfs, devops

I have created a new server to move our TFS 2015 to.

It is a Server 2019 with SQL Server 2019.

I backed up the TFS databases (Configuration and DefaultCollection)

I put those on the new server and installed DevOps 2022

Everything went well as expected.  But this was a trial run to make sure all went well.

Now a few weeks later after testing etc. I am ready to do the real move to production.

I made a backup of the old Production TFS databases as I did before and restored them to the new DevOps Box.

No wizard ran to upgrade the databases to the new version of DevOps like happened on the original install.

Do I have to uninstall DevOps 2022 and reinstall to get things correct?

I didn't see instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only way was to uninstall and reinstall the software yet again.  In the process I did restore my databases with the latest backup of our earlier version of TFS.

It did work but having to actually uninstall and reinstall this was a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the dry-run upgrade is done in a pre-production environment different than the production environment.

If you have done the dry-run upgrade in the production environment, that means the application of Azure DevOps Server 2022 had been installed in the production environment.

To complete the production upgrade, sure, you can try to un-install the application installed previously for the dry-run upgrade, then re-install and re-configure the application for the production upgrade.

For more details, you can reference the following documentations:

- [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2022)
- [Do a dry run of your upgrade in a pre-production environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/pre-production?view=azure-devops-2022)

Comment: That is correct,  I did run a dry run in my production environment and it went as expected.

I am now ready to do the real move to production, and I am seeing the easiest way is to 
    1.  Un-Install DevOps,
    2.  Restore latest bakups of TFS Databases (Config / DefaultCollection)
    3.  Re-Install DevOps

Comment: @Rog, Yes. Just go to try as the steps.

Comment: So it does NOT upgrade the database again unless you uninstall and re-install the DevOps software.